# Convert a piece of iOS code to Android

Tags: android, objective-c, android-animation, porting

I think from the title this question is a little bit confusing and will attract many (-) but you will see that its very interesting.

I have code my nice app for iOS and with a friend we want to port it in **Android**. Everything went ok except from a piece of code.

In my iOS app i have a UIView shown when UIWebview is loading,animating it.When UIWebview is finished loading i have it hidden.
The animation i made with the `animateWithDuration` function.
Here we are:

**The UIView:**

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *animationLayer;
_animationLayer.hidden=YES;
```

**Initialize it in Viewdidload**

```
_animationLayer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    _animationLayer.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random() % 255)/255.0f green:(arc4random() % 255)/255.0f blue:(arc4random() % 255)/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    _animationLayer.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
```

**On loading show the UIView and start animating it:**

```
- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[UIView animateWithDuration:7.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{ _animationLayer.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random() % 255)/255.0 green:(arc4random() % 255)/255.0 blue:(arc4random() % 255)/255.0 alpha:1.0f];}
                 completion:nil];
}
```

**Hide it on finish loading**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    _animationLayer.hidden=YES;
}
```

Here's how i think it could be made in Android.
Have a customized progressbar shown on loading and hidding it when done. The progressbar could be customized in a fullscreen canvas which changes it's color like the iOS code above.But no luck! :(
Any suggestion or an easy way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: "But no luck!" - elaborate, please.

Comment: can't implement the animation of the progress bar.Meaning change the background color in every step.I was thinking if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Why is your animation duration set to 7 seconds? You don't know how long the web call is going to take. Have you tried using Androids AsyncTask to allow you to setup animation while webcall is loading

Comment: setting the duration to 7 seconds didn't do any harm to the functionality of the animation.

Comment: My point was that when you have a web call and you want an animation in the background, the animation should  continue as long as the web call is still in progress. If you set the animation to 7 seconds and the web call goes on longer than 7 seconds, then the animation will finish in that state and stay that way. This is bad practice as the user may think the app has crashes.

Comment: we are talking about the iOS app.I could try longer animation duration.Thanks for pointing out this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in order to get an animation going for Android in the background while web call is being made, use AsyncTask. It looks like this

```
   private class WebCallOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
            private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {

                //web call code here

                //response returned here
                return "";
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
                if (this.dialog.isShowing())
                {
                    this.dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override


protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading");
            this.dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

In the example code I have just given, I have added the ProgressDialog in, this is usually what I use while making a web call, however you can replace that with whatever you want. You  can add your own view in, and animate that instead. Animate it in the pre execute method, then finish the web call in the post execute method.

Bit of advice on the IOS app, I mentioned in the comment already about the duration issue. I also think you should research block code for carrying out web calls. If you wish I can provide some example code, would make life a lot easier for you

EDIT:

Objective-C Block code. Create this class here

Interface class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WebCall.h"

@interface WebCall : NSObject
{
    void(^webCallDidFinish)(NSString *response);

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;

-(void)setWebCallDidFinish:(void (^)(NSString *))wcdf;

-(void)webServiceCall :(NSString *)sURL_p : (NSMutableArray *)valueList_p : (NSMutableArray *)keyList_p;

@end
```

Implementation class

```
#import "WebCall.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation WebCall

@synthesize responseData;

-(void)setWebCallDidFinish:(void (^)(NSString *))wcdf
{
    webCallDidFinish = [wcdf copy];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    NSLog(@"Response Code = %i", responseStatusCode);
    if(responseStatusCode < 200 || responseStatusCode > 300)
    {
        webCallDidFinish(@"failure");
    }



    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{

    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"WebCall Error: %@", error);
    webCallDidFinish(@"failure");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        response = [response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        webCallDidFinish(response);

}

-(void)webServiceCall :(NSString *)sURL_p : (NSMutableArray *)valueList_p : (NSMutableArray *)keyList_p
{
    NSMutableString *sPost = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    //If any variables need passed in - append them to the POST
    //E.g. if keyList object is username and valueList object is adam will append like
    //http://test.jsp?username=adam
    if([valueList_p count] > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < [valueList_p count]; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                    [sPost appendFormat:@"%@=%@", [valueList_p objectAtIndex:i],[keyList_p objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            else
            {

                    [sPost appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", [valueList_p objectAtIndex:i], [keyList_p objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }


    NSData * postData = [sPost dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];



    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL_p];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (theConnection)
    {
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }


}

@end
```

Then you to make this web call, you call it like this

```
 WebCall *webCall = [[WebCall alloc] init];


    [webCall setWebCallDidFinish:^(NSString *str){

        //This method is called as as soon as the web call is finished
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }];


    //Make web call here
    [webCall webServiceCall:@"http://www.bbc.co.uk/" :nil :nil];
```

See the setWebCallDidFinish method, it will not be called until the webcall has finished. So if you need to execute some code as soon as the web call as finished, such as stopping the animation, call it in that method there. Hope that helps

Comment: Nice example,thank you i will try it that way. As for the block code be my guest,after all Stack Overflow is for making us a better developer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for late reply, was away from computer until this morning. I added a custom web call class I use when making web calls. See my edit. Hope that helps. If you have any questions about it just ask.

Comment: Just wont to add that your code has a bug here: `if(responseStatusCode < 200 | responseStatusCode > 300)` where you need to use the logical operator `||` (even though, the bit operator `|` alway yields the same result ;)   Then, the code also needs more error checks, and it should be mentioned, that the implementation for encoding "form data set" is very primitive - and only works for the attributes and values encoded in ASCII which also must not have spaces and other "special characters". A proper encoding of the form data set is unfortunately unduly complex.

Comment: Oops my mistake regarding the operator, will fix that now. You can add more error checks as needed, I have few more additions in the version I use, but the above code is just a template I have saved for reference. As for the encoding, agreed, it can be rather annoying depending on what data is being returned, some special characters can cause quite a lot of trouble, but the above code should suffice for most basic requests

Comment: Wow,thank you very much,you gave a lot of material to read and test/play. For sure i will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to try something like [Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/). It uses clang and compiles all your objective-c to native ARM code for Android. Everything you are doing would run out of the box on top of that SDK on android.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[ObjC2J](http://code.google.com/p/objc2j/)**.

ObjC2J is an open-source library tool that translates Objective-C (Mac OS X) code to Java for the PC platform.